# Apply JSON format via Curl POST

Tags: json, bash, curl

I am trying to apply a long JSON via curl POST, but fails probably due to syntax. The script also contains multiple arrays in order to fulfil the script variables. 
When I run the script in order to print (echo) the JSON, it prints successfully the JSON, which is also validated. 
When I run the script in order to apply the JSON (curl -X POST), it fails.

Is there any other option in order to apply the JSON without modifying it?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` header value to Post the JSON data to curl command line.

For example :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"abc","password":"abc"}'  https://api.xyz.com/v2/login
```

Comment: I am applying the -H "Content-Type: application/json", but it fails at the data body.

Comment: can you please post more details on error message and sample command you are executing ?

Comment: But IS your json valid...? A first check might be `cat foo.json | jq empty`.